# How many moves?

Tags: mathematics

A move is one circle being moved to another place.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about;

[image: eazy]

Which is able to be done in 3 moves.

A more challenging one-[image: challenge-accepted]

How many moves minimum?

Comment: You'll need to specify what a "move" is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of moves required is:

> 18

The formula is:

> $$h = \text{height of triangle}\\\text{moves}=\left\lfloor\dfrac{h(h+1)}6\right\rfloor$$

Image of solution:

> [image]